# Consider removing the Ceramic tag

Tags: discussion

I believe that [the Ceramic tag](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ceramic) is not useful. It currently has no usage guidance. It overlaps substantively with other tags. Edit: should we remove the ceramic tag?

It is rarely used, which may indicate that it's of limited utility. Of the 7 current questions with this tag:

- 2 relate to ceramic (or PEO) coatings on rim brake rims. First, this arguably falls under questions related to rims or to brakes. Second, this is not a common feature even in high-performance alloy rims. It is not likely to become so, because performance bikes are evolving to use disc brakes.
- 4 relate to ceramic bearings. These should fall under the tag for bearings anyway.
- The last one refers to a ceramic coating on a cassette. Some of these cassettes exist, but they aren't offered by mainstream manufacturers. Ceramic coating is actually relatively rough at a microscopic level. I suspect they would *increase* drivetrain friction. Mainstream manufacturers may offer nickel or other coatings on their higher-level cassettes to *decrease* friction.

One counterargument is that there's a clear, if small, market for ceramic bearings on high-end performance bikes. Removing the tag might make it harder for users to find questions related to ceramic bearings, or ceramic other stuff.

Comment: Ceramic bearings have been a hot topic at times and probably will be again. I think keeping it in some form would be a good idea, but maybe turn it into something like "ceramic-bearing" and break it off from the other 3 questions?

Comment: @NathanKnutson In the interim, I proposed usage guidance for the ceramic tag. I focused it solely on ceramic bearings. I did this because ceramic or PEO coated rims are such a niche product. Now, if folks think that ceramic coatings should be included in the tag, I can think of a way to rewrite it.